ubuntu 22.04 LTS not loading USB drive
command lsusb shows disk

but fdisk and lsblk do not, only sda;


Could your USB device be sda?  Such things depend upon the way your machine enumerates devices. I'm running off a USB SDD, and it is sda, with the internal disk nvme0n1.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

topic to be closed, it turned out that the fault lies with ESX, more than one device connected via USB does not work, when I plug in only this disk, it is immediately visible
